# How to prove that the circle is not a function in the language of set theory

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Could you please explain to me why the circle defined by the equation $x^2+y^2=1$ is not considered a function by using the language of set theory ? And why should we want that one x defines exactly one y, what is the problem with the fact that one x defines multiples y ?

The motivation is that a function is defined to be the set of ordered pairs so it seems to me that it is valid to have at the same time the pairs $(x=0;y=1)$ and $(x=0; y=-1)$ in the set which defines the function. And by accepting the fact that there can be several y corresponding to one x, we don't need to bother whether a "function" is really a function or not ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The equation of the circle defines a *relation* in set-theoretic terms. Why is not a *function*? Because it does not satisfy the definition of [Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)): a relation involving sets $X$ and $Y$ that "assigns to each element of $X$ **exactly one** element of $Y$."

Comment: Re the title: your example is the proof. Id $C(0,1) = \{ (x,y) \mid x^2+y^2=1 \}$ we have that $(0,1), (0, -1) \in C(0,1)$. Thus, there are two elements of $Y$ assigned to $0$ and not "exactly one".

Comment: It is just a matter of *definition*. What you ask is: "why is a relation not necessarily a function?"  A similar question is: "why is a real number not necessarily a rational number?"

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Your argument is right if you talk about a specific class of functions. However, it is ultimately wrong that you cannot have a function which image is the unit circle. You implicitely assume that $X \subseteq \mathbb R$. But that does not have to be the case (see my answer).

Comment: Yaddle: Certainly there exist functions whose image is the unit circle (e.g. the identity function on the unit circle); nothing in the comment of @MauroALLEGRANZA implies otherwise. What that comment says, in answer to the question asked, is that the relation $x \sim y$ defined by the equation $x^2+y^2=1$ is not a function.

Answer (score 4):

In set theory, a function is not any set of ordered pairs. It is a set of ordered pair for which two distinct ordered pairs can't have the same first element.